# What software is most suitable to make simple visual diagrams from my excel worksheet inputs? [Structural Engineering Application]

Tags: windows, software-development

I am looking for some guidance on what programming language I should use to generate figures based upon a series of inputs. The figures will look similar in nature to this: https://ibb.co/hfsP1M7

I have created an excel workbook (with minimal VBA currently) which will take inputs corresponding to the spacing of the gridlines for a building (depicted alphabetically for length, numerically for width as per figure). The worksheet outputs a series of pressure diagrams and forces for the roof and walls of the given building.

I was thinking this could be capable in python with generating the figures with a series of straight lines between nodes (x,y points defined in excel)?

Thank you in advance for any advice.
Glenn.